# Use Vatsimphp API to Generate Number of Online Users

Tags: php, html

I have implemented the following [PHP module](https://github.com/skymeyer/Vatsimphp) onto my web server.

I have also set up a cron job to refresh the data every 5 minutes.

Now I am wondering how to use the included API to display the number of users connected to the VATSIM network on the frontpage of my main site.

I am unfamiliar with APIs and am a bit of a PHP novice so I would appreciate any help you can give me.

The API examples given are:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Vatsimphp package
 *
 * Copyright 2013 - Jelle Vink <jelle.vink@gmail.com>
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */

/**
 * Consult the documentation for more details at:
 * https://github.com/skymeyer/Vatsimphp/blob/master/docs/index.md
 */

use Vatsimphp\VatsimData;

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$vatsim = new VatsimData();
$vatsim->loadData();

// General vatsim statistics
$general = $vatsim->getGeneralInfo()->toArray();

// List all pilots
$pilots = $vatsim->getPilots()->toArray();

// List all controllers
$controllers = $vatsim->getControllers()->toArray();

// List all clients (pilots and controllers)
$clients = $vatsim->getClients()->toArray();

// List all servers
$servers = $vatsim->getServers()->toArray();

// List all voice servers
$voice = $vatsim->getVoiceServers()->toArray();

// List all prefile registrations
$prefile = $vatsim->getPrefile()->toArray();

// Search clients based on call sign
$aal = $vatsim->searchCallsign('AAL')->toArray();

// Search clients based on vatsim id
$user = $vatsim->searchVatsimId('1165529')->toArray();

// Get the METAR for KSFO
$ksfo = $vatsim->getMetar('KSFO');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found as follows:

.php file:

```
<?php
require_once 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Vatsimphp\vendor\autoload.php';

$logFile ='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Vatsimphp\vendor\skymeyer\vatsimphp\app\logsusers.log';

$vatsim = new \Vatsimphp\VatsimData();
$vatsim->setConfig('cacheOnly', true);
$vatsim->setConfig('logFile', $logFile);

   if ($vatsim->loadData()) {
   $info = $vatsim->getGeneralInfo()->toArray();
}

?>

<?php
   echo "<style=\"color: white;\">Total Users Online: <b>{$info['connected_clients']}</b>.";
 ?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_vatsim() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/online.php',
            data: {
                request: 'true'
            },
            success: function(reply) {
                $('.vatsim').html("" + reply + "");
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
  get_vatsim();
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="vatsim"></div>
```